# Symfony2 - How to pass in pagination code as a service?

Tags: symfony, service, doctrine-orm, pagination

I'm new to Symfony2 and would a step by step guidance how to pass in my pagination code as a service so I don't have to repeat the code and practice good coding habits.

Here is the original pagination code in the controller that I'd like to pass into a service.

I understand I need to setup my services: **(beyond this I need help on how to call the variables in my pagination.php service class into the controller to pass into twig)**

**config.yml**

```
services:

    pagination:
        class: Demo\ProjectBundle\Services\Pagination
        arguments: ["$request_stack", @doctrine]
        scope: request
```

**Pagination class (service)**

```
class Pagination
{
protected $request;

public function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack, Registry $doctrine)
{
    $this->request = $requestStack->getCurrentRequest();
    $this->doctrine = $doctrine;
}

public function pagination()
{
    //$page = $request->get('page');
    $page = $this->request->query->get('q');

    $count_per_page = 5;
    $total_count = $this->getTotalBlogs();
    $total_pages = ceil($total_count/$count_per_page);

    if (!is_numeric($page)) {
        $page = 1;
    } else {
        $page = floor($page);
    }

    if ($total_count <= $count_per_page) {
        $page = 1;
    }

    if (($page * $count_per_page) > $total_count) {
        $page = $total_pages;
    }

    $offset = 0;

    if ($page > 1) {
        $offset = $count_per_page * ($page - 1);
    }

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $blogQuery = $em->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('b')
        ->from('DemoProjectBundle:Blog', 'b')
        ->addOrderBy('b.created', 'DESC')
        ->setFirstResult($offset)
        ->setMaxResults($count_per_page);

    $blogFinalQuery = $blogQuery->getQuery();

    $blogPage = $blogFinalQuery->getArrayResult();

    foreach ($blogPage as $blog) {
        $blog_id = $blog['id'];
        $commentRepository = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('DemoProjectBundle:Comment');

        $comments[] = $commentRepository->findByBlog($blog_id);
    }

    return array(
        'blogPage'     => $blogPage,
        'total_pages'  => $total_pages,
        'current_page' => $page,
        'comments'     => $comments,
    );
}
}
```

**PageController (with pagination code I want to put into a service)**

```
class PageController extends Controller
{
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    // Pagination code
    $page = $request->get('page');

    $count_per_page = 5;
    $total_count = $this->getTotalBlogs();
    $total_pages = ceil($total_count/$count_per_page);

    if (!is_numeric($page)) {
        $page = 1;
    } else {
        $page = floor($page);
    }

    if ($total_count <= $count_per_page) {
        $page = 1;
    }

    if (($page * $count_per_page) > $total_count) {
        $page = $total_pages;
    }

    $offset = 0;

    if ($page > 1) {
        $offset = $count_per_page * ($page - 1);
    }

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $blogQuery = $em->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('b')
        ->from('DemoProjectBundle:Blog', 'b')
        ->addOrderBy('b.created', 'DESC')
        ->setFirstResult($offset)
        ->setMaxResults($count_per_page);

    $blogFinalQuery = $blogQuery->getQuery();

    $blogPage = $blogFinalQuery->getArrayResult();

    foreach ($blogPage as $blog) {
        $blog_id = $blog['id'];
        $commentRepository = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('DemoProjectBundle:Comment');

        $comments[] = $commentRepository->findByBlog($blog_id);
    }

    return $this->render('DemoProjectBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array(
        'blogPage'     => $blogPage,
        'total_pages'  => $total_pages,
        'current_page' => $page,
        'comments'     => $comments,
    ));
}
```

**index.html.twig**

```
{% block body %}
{% for blog in blogPage %}
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8 blog-main">
                <div class="blog-post">

                    <h2 class="blog-post-title">{{ blog.title }}</h2>
                        <p class="blog-post-meta"><time datetime="{{ blog.created|date('c') }}">{{ blog.created|date('l, F j, Y') }}</time> by <a href="#">{{ blog.author }}</a></p>

                    <div class="comment">
                        <p><small>Comments: {{ comments[loop.index0]|length }}</small>   </p>
                    </div>
                        <p>{{ blog.blog|truncate(350, true) }}</p><br>

                    <div class="tags">
                        <p><strong><small>Tags: </small></strong><span class="highlight">{{ blog.tags }}</span></p>
                    </div>
                        <p class="continue"><a href="{{ path('demo_project_show', { 'id': blog.id, 'slug': blog.slug }) }}">More reading&raquo </a></p>
                    <hr>

                </div><!-- /.blog-post -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}


{% block pagination %}
<ul class="pager">
    {% if total_pages > 0 %}
        <div class="pagination">
            <ul>
                {% for i in 1..total_pages %}
                    {% if loop.first %}
                        <li class="{% if current_page == 1 %} {% endif %}"><a href="{{ path('demo_project_homepage', { 'page':current_page - 1 }) }}">Previous</a></li>
                    {%endif%}

                    {% if loop.last %}
                        <li class="{% if current_page == total_pages %} {% endif %}"><a href="{{ path('demo_project_homepage', { 'page':current_page + 1 }) }}">Next</a></li>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </div>
    {% endif %}
</ul>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you define the service, it's available in the service container, which you can access from the controller.

Service definition:

```
services:
    pagination:
        class: Demo\ProjectBundle\Services\Pagination
        arguments: [@request_stack] # use @ to refer another services
        scope: request
```

In your controller:

```
class PageController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        $pagination = $this->container->get("pagination");
        ...
    }
}
```

Then it's just a matter of putting your pagination code in the `Pagination` class. This class structure depends on your design, but normally you have one or more public methods to pass data from the controller for the service to do it's logic and then returning the expected response.

**EDIT**

To get data from your service to the controller, return them in a way you can use them later in your templates or wherever you need it. One way of doing this is using arrays:

**Returning an array**

```
class Pagination
{
    public function getPaginationData()
    {
        return array('blogPage' => $blogPage, total_pages' => $total_pages, 'current_page' => $page, 'comments' => $comments);
    }
}
```

In your controller

```
$pagination = $paginationService->getPaginationData();

// return to the Twig template
return ['pagination_data' => $pagination];
```

In your twig template you can access the array as normal:

```
{{ pagination_data.blogPage }}
{{ pagination_data.total_pages }}
```

And so on so forth. You can replace the array for a class if you need more internal logic, even passing the full Pagination service to the Twig template. At the end it all depends on your application design.

Comment: I've updated my code with the pagination class to be used as the service. How would I access the variables I am using to pass to the twig template from the controller? ('blogPage' => $blogPage, total_pages'  => $total_pages, 'current_page' => $page, 'comments'     => $comments)

Comment: Edited to add a little explanation to what you asked.

Comment: Thanks for that, am testing this out and dumping out $pagination = $this->container->get("pagination") and have the following: (ContextErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Demo\ProjectBundle\Services\Pagination::__construct() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack, string given, called in /var/www/html/Project/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 1822 and defined in /var/www/html/Project/src/Demo/ProjectBundle/Services/Pagination.php line 14)

Comment: Change this: `arguments: ["@request_stack"]` for this `arguments: [@request_stack]`. You can see that you are passing an string :)

Comment: line 14 is this: public function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack, Registry $doctrine)

Comment: Ok that fixed the error so when creating a function getPaginationData() and inside with an array with the variables, don't I need to include in the original pagination method? Otherwise, I'm getting undefined variables in getPaginationData().

Comment: Of course, you should move all your pagination logic to that service, do whatever you want to do there, with the input necessary from the controller, and then return an array with the data the controller needs to pass to Twig.

Comment: Ok, because the original pagination method inside the pagination class already has a return array() etc. I thought you were suggesting to create another method to return the array of variables.

Comment: Ah, spoke too soon looks like when I click it just repeats page 1 of the entries. Looking at my pagination service method it looks like some of my 'get' commands (getQuery, getArrayResult, getSingleScalarResult) are showing up as not found in class w/ PHP Storm. Do I need to inject in something other than 'doctrine'?

Comment: Fixed it, `$page = $this->request->query->get('q')` in pagination method needed to be `$page = $this->request->query->get('page');`